# What strategies do the Excrucians use to destroy reality?

Tags: nobilis

I read the Nobilis 3rd edition book and while I have a rough idea on how to play the personalities of certain types of Excrucians, I don't really grasp the overarching strategies they might employ against reality.

I have some ideas, but I'm sure it's not all:

1. The most straight-forward is destroying the body of an Imperator, the PCs are actually created to safeguard it.
2. Destroy a Power and somehow extract the Estate.
3. Pervert the rules of a given world (such as Earth) to a point where it doesn't make sense and implodes.

I'm sure I'm missing the more esoteric or philosophical solutions, possibly even completely obvious ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*A Diary of Deceivers*, the sourcebook for playing Deceivers in Nobilis 3rd Edition, goes into some detail on Excrucian strategies. In addition, the recently-released *Glitch: A Story of the Not*, a separate game in the same setting, goes into more detail on the Lands Beyond Creation and the Excrucians, and provides a much more detailed breakdown of the **Flower Rite** and **Welken-Rite** described below.

The character creation chapter of *A Diary Of Deceivers* includes four main categories under "Your Plan", which are often stratagems in the War - "Build Something," such as a ritual or army; "Make a Pointed Argument," which includes using philosophical convolutions to weaken the foundations of reality; "Burn It All Down," which is about direct, unsubtle attacks like killing Imperators or unleashing direct, devastating force; and "Pay a Social Call," which suggests recruiting defenders of Creation to the cause.

There are also some specific common stratagems.

### The Flower Rite

The most common tool used to directly damage reality is the **Flower Rite**, which works by constructing or finding a situation that sets two of an Estate's properties in direct opposition, and using a ritual to interfere with the world's natural ability to heal from these. If this isn't disrupted, parts of the Estate, up to and including an entire Property, might be destroyed; but this can be prevented by ending whatever contradiction the Rite is hanging on.

*A Diary of Deceivers* uses an example of setting Cold's Properties that "Cold is melancholy" and "Cold descends" against each other by a few different suggested schemes, all of which centre on associating "down" with "happy".

Of course, this attracts the attention of the Estate and the Power, who will likely come and try to prevent the Rite; but if the Excrucian can fight off the Power, or keep the Rite sufficiently well hidden to do significant damage before the Power works out how it's being done, they can do a great deal of damage before fleeing.

### The Welken-Rite

Another strategy takes an opposite approach, by introducing a small piece of unreality, but soothing Creation so it accepts it in and grows around it. Once it's had time to take root, the Excrucian can use it as leverage, pulling the original seed of unreality back into the Not and ripping out however much of Creation it had taken root in with it.

Unlike the Flower Rite, the Welken-Rite doesn't rely on the Properties of Estates. It's generally done without a specific Estate as the target, as trying to root too deeply into an Estate will usually alert the Power, who may be able to unroot the fragment of unreality without damaging the rest of the world around it.

### Espionage

Any trick or stratagem from real-world espionage is a potential inspiration for the Excrucians. Suborning Powers so they'll turn double-agent and support the Not is a classic, as is framing them so they'll lose the trust of their peers. Either of these could be based on ideological grounds or more personal connections - getting a Power to share secrets with the enemy by blackmailing them over a breach of the Windflower Law is just as effective as actually convincing them of the superiority of the Not.

**Tairté ut-Napishtim** might be involved in this kind of work - he teaches Excrucian philosophy to anyone who'll listen. The Powers and Imperators tolerate him to try and learn about their enemies, but it's always possible someone will be swayed by his arguments.

They might also inflame the fault lines between the different Songs, turning Powers and Imperators against one another by bringing their ideological disputes into focus; this is unlikely to be enough to have Imperators kill one another, but turning their attention to infighting instead of the War is a victory for the Excrucian Host.

### Warfare

"Burn It All Down" above touches on this - it doesn't have to be complicated to work. Physically destroying things can weaken Creation's ability to fight, even if Destruction itself is an Estate. Imperators and their Nobles are common targets for this kind of work.

*Glitch* also goes into more detail on other denizens of the Not. Strategists and Warmains are both described as warleaders; as well as fighting directly themselves, the Excrucians lead their Not-Armies of Not-Soldiers directly against the borders of Creation, and may try to find hidden routes through the Weirding Wall to assault the less-guarded interior of Creation with whatever troops or monsters they can bring with them.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't played Nobilis since 1st edition, but the biggest attack strategy I would add to your list is:

- An attack on a particularly prominent example of an estate that will serve to weaken or destroy the estate itself.

This could be the basis of an adventure or even of a campaign.

For example:  in our game, I played 'Whimsy'.  If the most prominent example of Whimsy to my character was a beloved children's TV host, Excrucians might attack by manipulating the host and/or the news cycle into causing/revealing some scandal about them.

Another player in our group played 'Red Tape'.  This might be attacked by bolstering a presidential candidate that vowed to slash rules and regulations that prevent government employees from making their own decisions on the spot according to what they felt was best.  They might even be able to recruit the assistance of some other chancel's 'Individuality' to help, possibly under false pretenses.  (Which side your own players end up on in this struggle is up to you and them!)